# Testing a software vulnerabilites

Tags: security

Sort of in a soup now ..And sorry for being a bit generic.

I am an IT admin of a company and we have a small custom build software being used by one of the departments which was developed internally.Nobody seems to have the source code of it and the employee who created it has left. (This all happened before I joined)

Now as part of Security compliance implementation I need to test this software for vulnerabilities. I come from an IT infrastructure background and have no idea how to go about this .

Could some of you point me in the right direction

thanks

Comment: You need to hire an infosec company to execute an application security assessment. If you have no idea to go about this it is best left to the experts.

Answer (score 0):

**1. DIY**

There are a number of "black box" tests you can perform yourself.

The easiest to perform are web based tools that will scan for well known problems. Companies such as Qualys (Just referencing the best known player, not an endorsement) offer the needed tools to generate a security report that might (or might not) be enough to proof compliance (or non-compliance) with your requirements.

The mentioned company even offers some of those for free, provided the test target can be reached over the Internet. The more advanced options are obviously not going to be free.

**2. External Audit**

Alternatively you could seek an auditor familiar with the rules/regulations you seek compliance with and get them to certify it is in compliance. It can be tricky to find one willing to work on a black box system depending on the specific rules/regulations you want to proof compliance with.

**3. Ethical hacker**

Another option is to hire a company that will audit it by employing similar tools you could do yourself in a first phase, and depending on those results they might actually deploy a skilled hacker to break into the system. If they are good at what they do, it'll cost you a significant amount and If you allow them enough budget to do this, it's next to a sure thing that they will break in. [nothing is 100% secure, esp. not abandoned deployments]

The report afterwards will point out a list of improvements you need to make (but since you have no reasonable way to do that ... and your only goal is to get a compliance rubber stamp ...